# tex4ebook: error in compiling with configuration file

Tags: htlatex, miktex2.9, tex4ebook

My `myconfig.cfg` code block is:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}   
\Configure{AddCss}{blitz-lite.css}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

My command line is `tex4ebook -c myconfig test2.tex -f epub3 mathml` 
I get the following:

```
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: test2.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    4        LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `myconfig.cfg'.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    4        LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `myconfig.cfg'.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    4        LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `myconfig.cfg'.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
HTML Tidy for Windows released on 25 March 2009
        1 file(s) copied.
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
```

The `\begin{document}` is not missing in the config file. I saved the file in NotePad as `UTF-8`.

I also have `blitz-lite.css` saved in the working directory.

What could be the problem?

UPDATE: @michal.h21 correctly indicated that I might have an older version of `tex4ht`  This is what I see in the MikTex2.9 console 
[image: tex4ht packages]

There are two versions of ```tex4ht``.  Maybe the workflow is calling the old one?

Comment: I think this is the similar issue to the previous one. It seems TeX4ht files are quite old in Miktex and `\Configure{AddCss}` isn't available.

Comment: @michal.h21 You are correct. I removed the ```\Configure{AddCss}``` and it compiled with no error. I noticed this in MikTex

Comment: I will post an answer with a workaround

Comment: @michal.h21 Just FYI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this issue may be caused by missing definition for `\Configure{AddCss}` in Miktex. When you use undefined `\Configure` in the configuration file, the arguments end in the document content and you will get the `Missing \begin{document} in`myconfig.cfg'`error. You would get more detailed listing with the`-a debug`argument to`tex4ebook`:

```
tex4ebook -a debug -c myconfig test2.tex -f epub3 mathml
```

Anyway, as a workaround, you can use the definition of `\Configure{AddCss}` from TeX4ht sources:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}   
\NewConfigure{AddCss}[1]{%
  {\Configure{Needs}{File: #1}\Needs{}}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#1" />\Hnewline}}
}
\Configure{AddCss}{blitz-lite.css}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{Needs}` configuration register the CSS file as used file. It is necessary for the inclusion in the Epub file.

Comment: this works... Thanks

Comment: @MathDilettante I hoped so :) did you notice Miktex devels about the obsolete .4ht files?